# Problem making a post from xamarin to php on the server

Tags: php, http, xamarin, post

I'm making a post from my Xamarin c# code to the PHP file that is on the server. My problem is that I don't receive the data I'm sending.

Client:

```
        JObject oJsonObject = new JObject();
        oJsonObject.Add("Id", "eee");
        oJsonObject.Add("Referencia", 0);
        oJsonObject.Add("Nom_Pieza", 23);
        oJsonObject.Add("Cantidad", 4);
        oJsonObject.Add("Precio", 2.6);
        oJsonObject.Add("Importe", 1.1);

        private string URL = "http://10.3.148.92/WebServiceXamarin/index.php";
        //HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL);
        var Content = new StringContent(oJsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(URL, Content);


        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Server:

```
$Id = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, "Id"); 
$Referencia = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, "Referencia"); 
$Nom_Pieza = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, "Nom_Pieza"); 
$Cantidad = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, "Cantidad"); 
$Precio = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, "Precio"); 
$Importe = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, "Importe");
```

This is what I see when I run `echo var_dump($_REQUEST);` and `echo var_dump($_POST);`:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp64\www\WebServiceXamarin\index.php:27:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>
```

What am I doing wrong? I can see that the code is running but I don't seem to be receiving any data in my PHP variables.
Thank you

Comment: Try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and `var_dump($_POST);`. See if either contains the values you're looking for.

Comment: “Does this answer your question?” (formerly known as “Possible duplicate of”) [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: PHP does not populate $_POST, when you send data as `application/json` … see mentioned duplicate for info on how to access the data correctly in that case.

Comment: Okay you are right. Thank you!!! The solution is: $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );

$Id = $data->Id;

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );

$Id = $data->Id;
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please do not forget to mark your answer after three days, it will help others who have similar issue.